# Перестановки букв в слотах

Tags: c++, алгоритм, перестановка

Консольное приложение, язык C++. Есть 3 слота для букв, всего доступно 7 букв (условных A B C D E F G) для перестановок, без повторений (т.е. одну букву можно использовать только 1 раз). Позиция буквы в слове тоже не имеет значения (Т.е. ABC и CBA это одно и то же). За каждую определенную букву в слове приходится определенное действие (например, за букву А в слове, увеличить переменную NUM1 на 5, за каждую B - умножить NUM1 на 3, за каждую C - увеличить NUM1 на 6 и тд.).
[image: Примерная схема]
Задача собственно, сгенерировать все возможные варианты этих перестановок и вывести их все в консоль со значением переменной, полученной при комбинации, а также определить наилучшую (т.е. ту комбинацию, которая привела к наибольшему значению) и вывести на экран в виде текстового сообщения.

Хотелось бы понять, как алгоритмически с программной точки зрения реализовать этот процесс. Пока мыслей нет на этот счет, в качестве крайнего варианта единственное что приходит в голову это посчитать количество перестановок математически (7x6x5), получаем 210 вариантов, и задать эти 210 вариантов вручную [что-то вроде if(ABC) -> NUM1+=5+6+7, if (ABD) -> NUM1+=5+6+9 и тд].

Так же было бы желательно наложить это на предыдущие шаги, которые более простые. А именно 2-8+ этажей в каждом только 1 слот и 2-7 возможных буквы на слот (этот вариант примерно представляю как сделать самостоятельно).

UPD:
Добавил небольшой упрощенный пример программы и ее вывода. Первый раз тут так что заранее извиняюсь. Программа берет поочередно на каждом этаже, что представлена на схеме, одну из 2х комбинаций, получая условные (1-2-3), потом (1-2-4) и так далее через цикл, генерируя все 8 возможных вариантов и все значения для каждого из вариантов. Это у меня работает. Я просто не знаю как сделать так, чтобы на конечном этапе она еще и выбирала 3 буквы из 7 возможных и дополнительно накладывалась на уже сгенерированные варианты, к примеру, пару вариантов будет :

[1-2-3][ABC]

[1-2-3][ABD]

[1-2-4][ACE]

И так далее. т.е. таких вариантов будет ОЧЕНЬ много. И в каждом случае будет разное значение переменной NUM, и я как хочу найти наибольшее значение среди ВСЕХ вариантов. Составлял вопрос вроде как спокойно и осмысленно, но не знаю как выразиться еще более понятно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    using namespace std;
    float NUM = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            NUM += 5;
            break;
        case 1:
            NUM = NUM * 2;
            break;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
            case 0:
                NUM += 10;
                break;
            case 1:
                NUM = NUM * 1.5;
                break;
            }

            for (k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                switch (k)
                {
                case 0:
                    NUM += 2;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    NUM = NUM * 4;
                    break;
                }
                cout << "\nNUM = " << NUM;
                switch (k)
                {
                case 0:
                    NUM -= 2;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    NUM = NUM / 4;
                    break;
                }
            }
            switch (j)
            {
            case 0:
                NUM -= 10;
                break;
            case 1:
                NUM = NUM / 1.5;
                break;
            }       
        }
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            NUM -= 5;
            break;
        case 1:
            NUM = NUM / 2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Давайте по кусочку, а то ваши "увеличить NUM1 на 6 и тд." предельно неконкретны. На картинках цифры вообще непонятно при чем... Потом какие-то этажи... :( Итак, как я понимаю, вам надо 1. просто сгенерировать все возможные сочетания по 3 из 7. Здесь есть проблема? Затем 2. для каждого сочетания применить "бизнес-логику" — тут вообше непонятно: если порядок неважен, то что делать — сначала прибавлять 5 за А, или умножать на 3 за В - результаты-то будут категорически разные? Словом, я бы на вашем месте сел, успокоился, прочел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, и переделал бы вопрос.

Comment: количество перестановок математически - 5х5х5=125. Судя по условию, вам всего лишь нужно просто получить все комбинации по 3 буквы из 7.

Comment: @DmitryK О 125 можно подробнее? А то что-то терзают смутные сомнения...

Comment: @Harry
 Обновил вопрос.
Также отвечаю DmitryK,
Насчет 5x5x5 думаю неверно будет. Сначала берем 1 из 7 кубиков. 7 Вариантов. Его забираем из общей пачки, остается 6 для выбора. 7x6. Его тоже забираем из общей пачки. Остается только 5, при уже 2х выбранных.

7x6x5 думаю будет наиболее корректным решением, хотя, учитывая, что они без повторений, и место кубика в слове тоже не имеет значения, я могу ошибаться.

Comment: @Harry По условию задачи всегда берется по 3 буквы. Нельзя взять 1 букву или 2 буквы. Если алгоритмически - 3 вложенных цикла, 1 буква перебирается по индексам от 0 до 4, вторая от 1 до 5, а третья - от 2 до 6. Каждая буква - 5 комбинаций. В итоге 5х5х5. Raven - если про кубики, то мы всегда берем сразу по 3 кубика. Один кубик вернули, взяли другой. В итоге для каждого кубика - 5 вариантов.

Comment: @DmitryK можно небольшой пример в виде кода? Хотя бы 3 слота при 4х буквах. Чтобы была генерация всех возможных вариантах букв, а я попробую на это дело наложить математику (т.е. за каждую определенную букву в слове делать действие с переменной).

В целом понял что вы имеете в виду, но пока не очень понимаю как это должно работать.

Comment: Вы знаете, я даже ошибся. Получается всего 35 комбинаций. Код сейчас приведу.

Comment: @DmitryK Ну правильно, C_7^3 = 7!/3!/4! = 7\*6\*5 /(2\*3) = 35...

Comment: После обновления вопроса легче не стало, сдаюсь, умываю руки...

Comment: @Raven Ответьте пожалуйста коротко - да или нет: вам нужно получить все комбинации по 3 буквы из 7, а потом в зависимости от букв произвести над NUM1 3 арифметические операции? Потому что ваши попытки решения только сильнее запутывают.

Comment: @DmitryK , да, Ваш код сгенерировал все возможные комбинации по 3 из 7 без повторений и без значения порядка букв. Я попробовал на его основе модифицировать до 4 из 7 и 5 из 7, вроде работает корректно. Извиняюсь что долго могу не отвечать, попутно пытаюсь читать теорию перестановок :D .

На каждую букву в слове (не обязательно Num1 только, можно даже сказать что над разными переменными) надо произвести определенные действия. Например:
Если в слове есть А - к NUM1 добавить 2.
Если в слове есть B - к NUM2 добавить 5.
Если в слове есть C - умножить NUM3 на 3 ... и так далее.

Comment: @DmitryK

Как видите, порядок букв в слове не важен, важно само их присутствие. Другое дело я сейчас думаю, если этих вариантов было бы 4к+, то проще было их сгенерировать циклом и проверять есть ли в слове символ char "a", "b" и так далее, и на основе этого модифицировать переменные. Но если их всего 35 - может проще задать их втупую? Все 35 вариантов. И ресурсы сэкономим, не нагружая программу дополнительной генерацией, и проверять символы не будет нужно - на каждый вариант сразу будем знать что делать.

Comment: Ресурсы не сэкономите, а только потратите. Циклы все равно будут - будете буквы проверять. Тут осталось только функции посчитать и всё. Прямо в этих же циклах. Функция, которую я написал, делает действие в зависимости от буквы над любой переменной, которую ей передали.

Comment: @DmitryK, Хух, вроде закончил. Программа получилась очень большой. Проблемы на 219 и 233 строках обозначил комментариями, ибо я еще даже не запихивал туда цикл с 35-ю вариантами кубиков - а уже получил недостаток, она считает ОЧЕНЬ долго. Даже не знаю, это она просто печатает долго, или конкретно просчеты идут долго, но у меня считалось около минуты, если помножить это еще на 35 будет очень долго. Может можно как то по сеньеровски оптимизировать код, или разогнать саму VS, чтобы дать ей больше ресурсов системы на просчет. Я бы написал больше но увы символов тут маловато дают) Код в ответе.

Comment: @Harry, Вас тоже пингую. Может, прочитав код, что я скинул к ответу, Вы поймете, что я таки имел ввиду) Я старался комментариями расписать как можно более понятно, так что они там практически везде где есть место.

Comment: Вот уж по длинному коду восстанавливать задачу — точно увольте. Опять вы про какие-то этажи, схемы, слоты... Проблема в генерации? Чего? В вычислении? Чего? Без дальних рассказов о том, как один древний царь во сне увидел пирамиду с этажами и расставленными по ним воинами :) Коротко и точно *математически*.

Comment: @Harry, Хорошо что я успел прочитать правила поведения на данном ресурсе, и вместо того, чтобы ответить вам, как думаю, лучше не отвечу ничего). Скажу только вкратце, что судя по мемам, которые я видел про этот ресурс и про все ваши ответы - теперь я понимаю, откуда они взялись и что они более чем правдивы)

Ответ DmitryK кода по генерации 3 из 7 более чем удовлетворительный, и решает мою проблему. Просто накину их на этажи, а консоль заменю на вывод в файл, думаю побыстрее будет.

Программа работает, так что тему можно закрывать как [решено]. Ответ с решением пометил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код по генерации всех комбинаций по 3 буквы из 7.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* str = "ABCDEFG";
    const int strsize = 7;
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < strsize-2; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j < strsize-1; j++)
            for(int k=j+1; k<strsize; k++ )
            {
                cout << count << "\t" << str[i] << str[j] << str[k] << "\n";
                count++;
            }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Дальше вам нужна функция, которая в зависимости от буквы (индекса) делает определенную операцию. Ну что-то вроде:

```
int foo(int num, int operation)
{
    switch(operation)
    {
        case 0: return num + 1;
        case 1: return num + 1;
        case 2: return num + 1;
        case 3: return num + 1;
        case 4: return num + 1;
        case 5: return num + 1;
        case 6: return num + 1;
    };
}
```

Добавляете в цикл, считаете результат, сразу ищете максимум и всё.

Comment: Это при условии, как вы сказали, что "Позиция буквы в слове тоже не имеет значения (Т.е. ABC и CBA это одно и то же)". Но вообще-то, на арифметические операции порядок букв влияет. Если учитывать порядок букв, то тогда и комбинаций будет больше. Их будет 210.

Comment: Плохо только, что если букв, скажем, 20, а слотов, скажем, 17, то потребуется 17 вложенных циклов :) И вообще, этот метод не позволяет работать с числом слотов, определяемых во время выполнения...

Comment: Да. Тогда можно вызывать рекурсивно функцию. Либо рекурсию заменить стеком. Но здесь явно учебная задача, чтоб студенты научились генерировать все комбинации.

Comment: Или посмотреть в 4 том Кнута, или сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286517/9123401

Comment: Лучше конечно 4 том Кнута. А ответ по ссылке староват. Сейчас уже используется `std::next_permutation()`. Но тогда они же не поймут, как это вообще делать. Вот сейчас много вопросов по работе со списками. Можно же тоже не заморачиваться а использовать `std::list<>`. Я даже думаю что им читают курс "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" и Кнут явно на первой строчке в списке рекомендованной литературы.

Comment: Кстати, `std::next_permutation()` дает только все перестановки исходной строки, а не выборку 3 из 7. Так что надо читать теорию и делать руками.

Comment: Вы точно прочли *всё*, что написано по ссылке?

Comment: @Harry Извиняюсь, недочитал. Спасибо, интересный пост.

Answer (score 0):

Впринципе уже законченная программа, она работает, работает **правильно**, но медленно, я боюсь, если накинуть на ее еще эти 35 вариантов с кубиками, то минута просчета превратится в полчаса. Может, можно как то оптимизировать код или дать ресурсов Visual Studio на системном уровне, чтоб комп гудел но ресурсы процессора/видюхи работали на просчет программы больше?

```
//Program Max Crit for set <Venomous Smite>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    using namespace std;

    //Base Stats (Базовые параметры, которыми обладает персонаж)

    const float Base_Power = 4234;
    const float Base_Power_multiplier = 1.41;
    const float Base_Mana = 29160; // Если используем ультимативную способность - добавить к этому значению +10к
    const float Base_Mana_multiplier = 1.02;
    const float Base_penetr = 1487;
    const float Base_crit_power = 1.7;
    const float Base_minefield_dmg_multiplier = 1.125;
    const float Base_rune_dmg_multiplier = 1.125;
    const float Base_trap_dmg_multiplier = 1.225;
    const float Base_Enemy_resist = 33000;
    // const float Base_crit_chance = 0,3; // Не используется в данной программе


    //Skill Coefficients (Коэффициенты умений, скалирующие силу/ману в урон.)

    const float minefield_power_coef = 1.26053;
    const float minefield_mana_coef = 0.119984;

    const float rune_power_coef = 1.08501;
    const float rune_mana_coef = 0.103219;

    const float trap_power_coef = 0.542534;
    const float trap_mana_coef = 0.051638;

    //Variants (Возможные варианты на каждом этапе)

    string Race[3] = { "<HighElf>","<WoodElf>","<Khajit>" };
    string Mundus[3] = { "<Warrior>","<Lover>","<Shadow>" };
    string Weapon[7] = { "<Sword-Sword>","<Mace-Mace>","<Axe-Axe>","<Sword-Mace>","<Sword-Axe>","<Mace-Axe>","<FireStaff>" };
    string Trait[3] = { "<Nirn-Nirn>","<Sharpened-Sharpened>","<Nirn-Sharpened>" };
    string Shoulders[3] = { "<2M>","<1M1L>","<2L>" };
    string Skill[3] = { "<2Power>","<1Power1SorcMana>","<2Mana>" };

    //Calculations (Вычисления)

    float Power = Base_Power;
    float Power_multiplier = Base_Power_multiplier;
    float Mana = Base_Mana;
    float Mana_multiplier = Base_Mana_multiplier;
    float penetr = Base_penetr;
    float crit_power = Base_crit_power;
    float minefield_dmg_multiplier = Base_minefield_dmg_multiplier;
    float rune_dmg_multiplier = Base_rune_dmg_multiplier;
    float trap_dmg_multiplier = Base_trap_dmg_multiplier;
    float Enemy_resist = Base_Enemy_resist;

    int iRace = 0;      // 
    int iMundus = 0;    //
    int iWeapon = 0;    //
    int iTrait = 0;     // Блок счетчиков-переменных i,j,k и тд. для каждого цикла
    int iSkill = 0;     //
    int Number = 0;     //
    int iShoulders = 0; // 

    float Winner2x = 0; // 2 Переменные для финального счета умений (Мина + руна) и (Мина + руна + ловушка)
    float Winner3x = 0; //

    string WinnerRace2 = { "0" };      //
    string WinnerMundus2 = { "0" };    //
    string WinnerWeapon2 = { "0" };    //
    string WinnerTrait2 = { "0" };     //
    string WinnerShoulders2 = { "0" }; //
    string WinnerSkill2 = { "0" };     //
    // Блок инициализаций этапов для вывода комбинаций в конце программы
    string WinnerRace3 = { "0" };      //
    string WinnerMundus3 = { "0" };    //
    string WinnerWeapon3 = { "0" };    //
    string WinnerTrait3 = { "0" };     //
    string WinnerShoulders3 = { "0" }; //
    string WinnerSkill3 = { "0" };     //

    //Сам цикл, перебирающий все возможные варианты и выводящий на экран конечный результат и комбинацию, приведшую к этому результату
    for (iRace = 0; iRace < 3; iRace++)
    {
        switch (iRace)
        {
        case 0: //High elf: +258 power, +2000 mana
            Power += 258;
            Mana += 2000;
            break;
        case 1: //Wood elf: +950 penetration, +2000 mana
            penetr += 950;
            Mana += 2000;
            break;
        case 2: //Khajit: +915 mana, +12% crit power
            Mana += 915;
            crit_power += 0.12;
            break;
        }
        for (iMundus = 0; iMundus < 3; iMundus++)
        {
            switch (iMundus)
            {
            case 0: // Warrior: +389 power
                Power += 389;
                break;
            case 1: // Lover: +4489 penetration
                penetr += 4489;
                break;
            case 2: // Shadow : +18% crit power
                crit_power += 0.18;
                break;
            }
            for (iWeapon = 0; iWeapon < 7; iWeapon++)
            {
                switch (iWeapon) //(any dual weapon combination +80power) Each sword +142 power, Each mace +1650 penetration, Each axe +6% crit power, firestaff +10% dmg to minefield
                {
                case 0:
                    Power += 364;//284 + 80 (passive)
                    break;
                case 1:
                    penetr += 3300;
                    Power += 80;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    crit_power += 0.12;
                    Power += 80;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Power += 222; //142 + 80 (passive)
                    penetr += 1650;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Power += 222; //142 + 80 (passive)
                    crit_power += 0.06;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    penetr += 1650;
                    crit_power += 0.06;
                    Power += 80;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    minefield_dmg_multiplier += 0.1;
                    break;
                }
                for (iTrait = 0; iTrait < 3; iTrait++)
                {
                    switch (iTrait) //2 gem for 2 weapons (staff 2-handed, 1 gem on 2 hands)
                    {
                    case 0: //2 nirn gem + 235 power
                        Power += 235;
                        break;
                    case 1: //2 sharpened gem + 3276 penetration
                        penetr += 3276;
                        break;
                    case 2: //1 nirn + 1 sharpened gem, +200 power +1638 penetration
                        Power += 200;
                        penetr += 1638;
                        break;
                    }
                    for (iShoulders = 0; iShoulders < 3; iShoulders++)
                    {
                        switch (iShoulders)
                        {
                        case 0: //2 medium shoulder +4% power, +4% crit power
                            Power_multiplier += 0.04;
                            crit_power += 0.04;
                            break;
                        case 1: //1 medium +2% power + 2% crit power, 1 light +939 penetration. (if have light = +2% mana)
                            Power_multiplier += 0.02;
                            crit_power += 0.02;
                            penetr += 939;
                            Mana_multiplier += 0.02;
                            break;
                        case 2: //2 light +1878 penetration, (if have light = +2% mana)             
                            penetr += 1878;
                            Mana_multiplier += 0.02;
                            break;
                        }
                        for (iSkill = 0; iSkill < 3; iSkill++)
                        {
                            switch (iSkill)
                            {
                            case 0: //2 power skills on bar = +6% power
                                Power_multiplier += 0.06;
                                break;
                            case 1: //1 power 1 mana skills on bar = +5% power +8% mana
                                Power_multiplier += 0.05;
                                Mana_multiplier += 0.08;
                                break;
                            case 2: //2 mana skills on bar = +2% power + 15% mana
                                Power_multiplier += 0.02;
                                Mana_multiplier += 0.15;
                                break;
                            }
                            //33k resist = -50% dmg taken of target
                            Enemy_resist = Base_Enemy_resist - penetr;
                            float Clear_Minefield_dmg = (((Power * Power_multiplier * minefield_power_coef) + (Mana * Mana_multiplier * minefield_mana_coef)) * minefield_dmg_multiplier * crit_power);
                            float Clear_Rune_dmg = (((Power * Power_multiplier * rune_power_coef) + (Mana * Mana_multiplier * rune_mana_coef)) * rune_dmg_multiplier * crit_power);
                            float Clear_Trap_dmg = (((Power * Power_multiplier * trap_power_coef) + (Mana * Mana_multiplier * trap_mana_coef)) * trap_dmg_multiplier * crit_power);
                            float Minefield_dmg = Clear_Minefield_dmg * (1 - (Enemy_resist / 66000));
                            float Rune_dmg = Clear_Rune_dmg * (1 - (Enemy_resist / 66000));
                            float Trap_dmg = Clear_Trap_dmg * (1 - (Enemy_resist / 66000));
                            if ((Minefield_dmg + Rune_dmg) > Winner2x)
                            {
                                WinnerRace2 = Race[iRace];
                                WinnerMundus2 = Mundus[iMundus];
                                WinnerWeapon2 = Weapon[iWeapon];
                                WinnerTrait2 = Trait[iTrait];
                                WinnerShoulders2 = Shoulders[iShoulders];
                                WinnerSkill2 = Skill[iSkill];

                                Winner2x = Minefield_dmg + Rune_dmg;
                            }
                            if ((Minefield_dmg + Rune_dmg + Trap_dmg) > Winner3x)
                            {
                                //string Winner3T[6] = { Race[iRace],Mundus[iMundus],Weapon[iWeapon],Trait[iTrait],Shoulders[iShoulders],Skill[iSkill] };
                                //[ПРОБЛЕМА] Пытался запихнуть вместо следующих 6 строк ту, что выше, пишет мол ошибка с операндом "=". Хотел чтобы каждую комбинацию записало в массив и вывело в конце, но не дает, пришлось сделать в виде 6-ти отдельных переменных.
                                WinnerRace3 = Race[iRace];
                                WinnerMundus3 = Mundus[iMundus];
                                WinnerWeapon3 = Weapon[iWeapon];
                                WinnerTrait3 = Trait[iTrait];
                                WinnerShoulders3 = Shoulders[iShoulders];
                                WinnerSkill3 = Skill[iSkill];

                                Winner3x = Minefield_dmg + Rune_dmg + Trap_dmg;
                            }
                            cout << "\nУрон минного поля = " << Clear_Minefield_dmg << " | Урон руны  = " << Clear_Rune_dmg << " | Урон ловушки  = " << Clear_Trap_dmg << " | Результирующий чистый урон = " << Clear_Minefield_dmg + Clear_Rune_dmg + Clear_Trap_dmg << "\nРезультирующий урон по цели = " << Minefield_dmg + Rune_dmg + Trap_dmg << " При сопротивлении в: " << Enemy_resist / 660 << "%\nКомбинация: " << Race[iRace] << Mundus[iMundus] << Weapon[iWeapon] << Trait[iTrait] << Shoulders[iShoulders] << Skill[iSkill];
                            cout << "\nСила: <" << Power << "> Множитель силы: <" << Power_multiplier << "> Мана: <" << Mana << "> Множитель маны: <" << Mana_multiplier << "> Пробитие: <" << penetr << "> Критический урон: <" << crit_power << ">\nМножитель урона мины: <" << minefield_dmg_multiplier << "> Множитель урона руны: <" << rune_dmg_multiplier << "> Множитель урона ловушки: <" << trap_dmg_multiplier << ">\n"; // Отладочная команда, можно закоментировать.
                            Number++;

                            //[ПРОБЛЕМА] Следующие свитчи вплоть до конца цикла, это возвращение к тем параметрам, что были ДО начала цикла. Мы взяли кубик, посчитали его значение, положили обратно. Сделал отнятием тех значений что прибавили, хотя не знаю, вероятно, можно сделать проще и умнее.
                            switch (iSkill)
                            {
                            case 0:
                                Power_multiplier -= 0.06;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Power_multiplier -= 0.05;
                                Mana_multiplier -= 0.08;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Power_multiplier -= 0.02;
                                Mana_multiplier -= 0.15;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        switch (iShoulders)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            Power_multiplier -= 0.04;
                            crit_power -= 0.04;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Power_multiplier -= 0.02;
                            crit_power -= 0.02;
                            penetr -= 939;
                            Mana_multiplier -= 0.02;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Mana_multiplier -= 0.02;
                            penetr -= 1878;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    switch (iTrait)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        Power -= 235;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        penetr -= 3276;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Power -= 200;
                        penetr -= 1638;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch (iWeapon)
                {
                case 0:
                    Power -= 364;//(-80 passive)
                    break;
                case 1:
                    penetr -= 3300;
                    Power -= 80;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    crit_power -= 0.12;
                    Power -= 80;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Power -= 222;//(-80 passive)
                    penetr -= 1650;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Power -= 222;//(-80 passive)
                    crit_power -= 0.06;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    penetr -= 1650;
                    crit_power -= 0.06;
                    Power -= 80;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    minefield_dmg_multiplier -= 0.1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            switch (iMundus)
            {
            case 0:
                Power -= 389;
                break;
            case 1:
                penetr -= 4489;
                break;
            case 2:
                crit_power -= 0.18;
                break;
            }
        }
        switch (iRace)
        {
        case 0:
            Power -= 258;
            Mana -= 2000;
            break;
        case 1:
            penetr -= 950;
            Mana -= 2000;
            break;
        case 2:
            Mana -= 915;
            crit_power -= 0.12;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nПобедитель [Минное поле + Руна]: " << WinnerRace2 << WinnerMundus2 << WinnerWeapon2 << WinnerTrait2 << WinnerShoulders2 << WinnerSkill2 << " При счете: " << Winner2x << "\nПобедитель [Минное поле + Руна + Капкан] = " << WinnerRace3 << WinnerMundus3 << WinnerWeapon3 << WinnerTrait3 << WinnerShoulders3 << WinnerSkill3 << "При счете: " << Winner3x << "\n\nКоличество сгенерированных вариантов:" << Number << "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно немного упростить, заодно и ускорить код.
Сначала сделать циклы, а потом в последнем делать все расчеты.
Не придется откатывать значения на предыдущие. Переменные будут локальными - лучше соптимизируются.

```
for (iRace = 0; iRace < 3; iRace++)
    for (iMundus = 0; iMundus < 3; iMundus++)
        for (iWeapon = 0; iWeapon < 7; iWeapon++)
            for (iTrait = 0; iTrait < 3; iTrait++)
                for (iShoulders = 0; iShoulders < 3; iShoulders++)
                    for (iSkill = 0; iSkill < 3; iSkill++)
                    {   // инициализация переменных
                        double Power = Base_Power;
                        ...
                        switch (iRace) {}
                        switch (iMundus) {}
                        switch (iWeapon) {}
                        switch (iTrait) {}
                        switch (iShoulders) {}
                        switch (iSkill) {}
                        
                        // расчет 
                        Enemy_resist = Base_Enemy_resist - penetr;
                        float Clear_Minefield_dmg =
                        ...
                    }
```